# Button Background Color do not change

Tags: wpf, button

I'm trying to change the background color of my button, but it does not work ...

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    btnGenerate.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
 }
```

I also tried to change the property in the properties window.

[image: Button Brush in Properties]

Not-Expected Result:

[image: Button background color not change]

Comment: Did you change the Button's ControlTemplate?

Comment: What you are posting here is correct. Post more of your code, so we can find out whats wrong together!

Comment: @Clemens no... its default (system.windows.controls.controltemplate)

Comment: @Clemens I created a new one, I inserted a button and everything worked. However, when I insert the canvas into the form, it appears to overwrite the color I selected and returns to the default